# Different PHP version in localhost folder

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, localhost, macos-mojave

I have a Wordpress site which will not work with PHP 7. The dozens of other sites I have on my local machine are all fine with  PHP 7. How can I change the PHP version in one folder on my localhost machine to version 5.4? I am running a Mac on Mojave with Apache. I have tried changing an .htaccess file by adding:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

Which I got from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server).

But every time I clicked a link the browser downloaded the page.

Apache version = Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix)

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this blog post](https://lorenzo.mile.si/macos-mojave-10-14-local-php-development-with-multiple-versions/916/) on running multiple versions of PHP in separate virtual hosts via FastCGI on Mac Mojave.

Comment: Thanks @Anaksunaman. Not heard of FastCGI. I'll check it out.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you get everything working as you need it to. =)